iOS Missing API Declarations warning _after_ adding privacy manifest
I still receive a warning email from Apple when I submit my .NET MAUI iOS app regarding Missing API declarations.
I have already added a PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file in my Platforms/iOS folder. Its Build Action is BundleResource. I also modified the project file to include the relevant ItemGroup information.
The email contains exactly the same missing API declarations as before I added the privacy file: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace, NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp, and
NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime.
Here is my PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file:
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<!-- See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/apple-privacy-manifest-support/ -->

<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>C617.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>35F9.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>E174.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I have already removed the comment line from the file for my next attempt, but I have no idea if that is the problem. Other ideas are welcome.

where you able to solve it??

You may refer to Adding Apple Privacy Manifest Support to .NET iOS & .NET MAUI apps. Please check the content of the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy. Seems you have missed the <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>.

@LiqunShen-MSFT Doh! Thanks - I should have noticed that long before now. I have no doubt that would break it, and I expect it should work for my next submission.


Apple is introducing a privacy policy for including privacy manifest files in new and updated applications targeted for iOS, iPadOS, and tvOS platforms on the App Store.
The privacy manifest file is a property list that records the types of
data collected by your app or third-party SDK, and the required
reasons APIs your app or third-party SDK uses.

For .NET MAUI Applications
First add a  PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy as BundleResources in the Platforms/iOS folder.(Ensure that the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file doesn't have an .xml extension.)
Then add required entries to the privacy manifest. Don't miss the NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes key.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>C617.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>35F9.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>E174.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>       
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

You may also edit your .NET MAUI project file to include the below section.
<ItemGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">
    <BundleResource Include="Platforms\iOS\PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy" LogicalName="PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy" />
</ItemGroup>

For more info, please refer to
Adding Apple Privacy Manifest Support to .NET iOS & .NET MAUI apps,
Apple privacy manifest.
Hope it helps!
